# DirectMail SingSendMail not working

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-direct-mail

I am trying the singleSendMail API from Alibaba Cloud's DirectMail, the request looks something like this

```
https://xx.xxxx.com/?Action=SingleSendMail
&AccountName=test@example.com
&ReplyToAddress=true
&AddressType=1   
&ToAddress=test1@example.com
&Subject=Subject
&HtmlBody=<body><h2>Test</h2></body>
```

I get a 400 error `MissingParameter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alibaba Cloud REST API has two sets of parameters plus the signature that you must include in your request.

Using Python as an example, you need to specify the public parameters as follows:

```
parameters = {}

# Add the DirectMail public request parameters
parameters["Format"] = "json"
parameters["AccessKeyId"] = credentials['AccessKey']
parameters["SignatureMethod"] = "HMAC-SHA1"
parameters["SignatureType"] = ""
parameters["SignatureVersion"] = "1.0"
parameters["SignatureNonce"] = get_uuid()
parameters["Timestamp"] = utc
parameters["Version"] = "2017-06-22"
parameters["RegionId"] = "ap-southeast-1"
```

The add the request parameters as follows. You will need to modify with your account information:

```
# Add parameters that are always set
parameters["Action"] = "SingleSendMail"
parameters["AddressType"] = "1"
parameters["ReplyToAddress"] = "true"

# Add the DirectMail API parameters
parameters["AccountName"] = dm_account
parameters["FromAlias"] = dm_alias
parameters["ToAddress"] = to_list
parameters["Subject"] = subject
parameters["HtmlBody"] = body
parameters["textBody"] = body_text
```

Then you will need to sign the request.

I wrote an article about Direct Mail and generating signatures with complete working source code in Python.

[DirectMail REST API](https://www.neoprime.io/info/alibaba/devops/day_05.php)